# Visual comaparaison of two graphs

Tags: r, social-networking, igraph, network-analysis

I would like to compare two graphs with the same number of nodes and some edges in common. When over-plotting the two graphs, I would like to highlight the edges that are different by having them in a different appear in a different color.  This is my code so far, thanks

```
  coords <- layout.fruchterman.reingold(g.s)

plot.igraph(g.n, layout=coords,main="Simulated VS Observed",
        rescale = T,
        edge.arrow.size=.1,
        edge.color="#2B60DE",
        vertex.size=5, 
        vertex.color="#DEA82A",
        vertex.frame.color="#DEA82A",

        vertex.label.dist=0.4,
        edge.curved=.3,
        vertex.label.color="black"
)

plot.igraph(g.s, layout=coords,main="",
        add=T,
        rescale = T,
        edge.arrow.size=.1,
        edge.color="Red",
        edge.width=1,
        vertex.size=5, 
        vertex.color="#DEA82A",
        vertex.frame.color="#DEA82A",
        edge.curved=.3,
        vertex.label=""
)
```

This what I want to compare
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fkkd.jpg)

This is something similar to what I wish to see except that I only want the different edges to be in a different color
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWVtm.jpg)

Comment: You should provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that we can run to see what happens. It would be even better of you make a sketch of the desired output.

Comment: can you add some data for g.n and g.s